# Filter by content type and shared taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to classify my content within the following categories:

- Technology
- International Politics
- Education
- Religion
- Sports

They are shared among my content types (e.g. news, page).
I want to create listing pages filtering by category, something like "news/international-politics" (notice the clean URL).

What is the best way to achieve this?

I've kind of done it with a shared taxonomy and a view per content type with an argument, but then I can't use the taxonomy links and have to build them by hand (cleaning the taxonomy name), but it's not a very clean solution.

Comment: For which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: drupal 6. I thought it wouldn't matter...

Comment: @sharpbites: Views for Drupal 7 is quite different from the version for Drupal 6. If then you are looking for a different module to use, there are modules without a Drupal 7 version, and the answer would change basing on which Drupal version you are interested to.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "cleaning the taxonomy name;" may you explain that part?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I want to clean all the special chars from the category in the same way transliteration does it. For example it should be "news/international-politics" and not "news/International Politics". (It should also filter other chars, not only applying downcasing and replacing spaces).

Comment: Pathauto is able to handle that. Have you tried it ?

Comment: @Haza. Yes, I have tried, it doesn't help here. I need taxonomies to link to view+argument and pathauto doesn't help here (unless I manually do pathauto_cleanstring on the term name and build the url by hand, which is what I am doing and is less than ideal)

Answer (score 1):

### To create the view

1. Create a view with appropriate fields/whatever.
2. Add the first argument *Node: Type*.
3. Add the second argument *Taxonomy: Term*.
4. For the second argument select *Transform spaces to dashes in URL*.

### To create the listing page

#### Option 1

Bite the bullet and create the page in code. You just need to iterate over the content types and terms, creating the links as you go.

#### Option 2

Create a normal view that lists the taxonomy terms. Use link rewriting in the view to output a link that's contains the term name and content type, and is easily identifiable. Eg. `custom_term_list/news/International Politics`. Use [custom_url_rewrite_outbound()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/custom_url_rewrite_outbound/6) to translate this to `/news/international-politics`. Gotta be careful not to slow the site down here.

#### Option 3

Use a *terms as nodes* paradigm. (I think this would work.) Create a content type for which each node will refer to a term. This can be done with taxonomy_node, nat (Node Auto Term), or even content_taxonomy (and maybe others for all I know). Add a computed_field that calculates the name of the term with spaces turned to dashes (or whatever). Then it would be easy to make the listing. If you want the node term to be created automatically when a term's created, then you'll need to use one of the first two modules mentioned.

Those are the only approaches I can think of to create listing pages. I think I'd just go for the first one.

Comment: Not really. That's what I have currently (I use multiple views instead of the node type as first argument, but that makes no difference). The problem is, I want to make a listing of the categories, each linking to its page (news/whatever-the-category-name)

Comment: @sharpbites So on one page you want to have links to news/technology, news/international-politics, etc., pages/technology, pages/international-politics, etc.?

Comment: No, each page has links to its own category pages. On news there are links to news/*. On blog there are links to blog/*

Comment: @sharpbites Actually makes no difference, you can still use all three approaches here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it using distinct vocabularies per content type togheter with nat and tvi.

Comment: can you expand on this a bit more so other could accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It took me days to work this out
but the answer is in this video

Hierarchical Views Catalog using Taxonomy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1jqu8JnLbU#t=511

**In Views Use The Rewrite results Output this field as a link**

Make sure your title field in the Taxonomy View doesn't link to the taxonomy term, but it outputs the field as a link to "catalog/[name]" that way your catalog names are clickable :)