# Filter taxonomy term on content type

Tags: views

I'm currently running Drupal 7 and have got some taxonomies setup.

I also have different content types which live under the same taxonomy terms but want to be able to filter a term by content type.

What's the best way to do this in Drupal 7? I've looked into the Views module which looks like it's the right way to go.

I've also looked at this article: http://www.braahm.be/posts/tuning-taxonomy-pages-page-manager-panels-views-and-custom-build-modes-drupal-7 and [Filter by content type and shared taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1996/filter-by-content-type-and-shared-taxonomy-terms) but they seem a bit over the top for what I want to achieve.

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views is the standard option for achieving your goal.  Check out [this video series](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) to learn more

Comment: That's great cheers Ashlar